How can I solve"clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1"?
I want to compile a simple “hello world” c program for x86_64-pc-windows-msvc using the clang compiler on windows.
I have installed Visual Studio 2019.
Command used
clang a.c
Error generated
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
These errors also happened with clang++.
Code of a.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hello,world");
    return 0;
}

Infomation with "-v"
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: E:\LLVM\bin
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang f
rom a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
 "E:\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.33.0 -emit-obj
 -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -dumpdir a- -disable-free -clear-as
t-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name a.c
 -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-cont
ract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x
86-64 -tune-cpu generic "-fdebug-compilation-dir=C:\\Novel_YouDao_Convertor\\Nov
el\\zzfd" -v "-fcoverage-compilation-dir=C:\\Novel_YouDao_Convertor\\Novel\\zzfd
" -resource-dir "E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18" "-IE:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\include"
 "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\
include" "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34
.31933\\ATLMFC\\include" "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Au
xiliary\\VS\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.
0.19041.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.190
41.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\
\um" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\shared
" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-
IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" -I.
 -internal-isystem "E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\include" -internal-isystem "C:/Pro
gram Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Progra
m Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Fi
les/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Pr
ogram Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program
Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessa
ge-length=80 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compati
bility-version=19.33 -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcolor-
diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\YvZhou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a-279e22.o" -
x c a.c
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-pc-window
s-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC
/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/
include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/
PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/in
clude"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/Pl
atformSDK/Include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.
0.19041.0\ucrt"
ignoring duplicate directory "E:\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\incl
ude
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt
 .
 E:\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:a.exe -defaultlib:libcmt -defaultlib:oldnames "-libpath:lib\\am
d64" "-libpath:atlmfc\\lib\\amd64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Ki
ts\\10\\Lib\\10.0.22621.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows
 Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.22621.0\\um\\x64" "-libpath:E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\lib\\
windows" -nologo "C:\\Users\\YvZhou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a-279e22.o"
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

C:\Novel_YouDao_Convertor\Novel\zzfd>clang a.c -v > a.txt
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: E:\LLVM\bin
clang: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try running Clang f
rom a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]
 "E:\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.33.0 -emit-obj
 -mrelax-all -mincremental-linker-compatible -dumpdir a- -disable-free -clear-as
t-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name a.c
 -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -ffp-cont
ract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x
86-64 -tune-cpu generic "-fdebug-compilation-dir=C:\\Novel_YouDao_Convertor\\Nov
el\\zzfd" -v "-fcoverage-compilation-dir=C:\\Novel_YouDao_Convertor\\Novel\\zzfd
" -resource-dir "E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18" "-IE:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\include"
 "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\
include" "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34
.31933\\ATLMFC\\include" "-IE:\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Au
xiliary\\VS\\include" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.
0.19041.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.190
41.0\\ucrt" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\
\um" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\shared
" "-IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-
IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Include\\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" -I.
 -internal-isystem "E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\include" -internal-isystem "C:/Pro
gram Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Progra
m Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program Fi
les/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -internal-isystem "C:/Pr
ogram Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/include" -internal-isystem "C:/Program
Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/PlatformSDK/Include" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessa
ge-length=80 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -fms-compati
bility-version=19.33 -fskip-odr-check-in-gmf -fdelayed-template-parsing -fcolor-
diagnostics -faddrsig -o "C:\\Users\\YvZhou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a-a20331.o" -
x c a.c
clang -cc1 version 18.1.8 based upon LLVM 18.1.8 default target x86_64-pc-window
s-msvc
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC
/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/
include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/
PlatformSDK/Include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/in
clude"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/Pl
atformSDK/Include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.
0.19041.0\ucrt"
ignoring duplicate directory "E:\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include"
  as it is a non-system directory that duplicates a system directory
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\incl
ude
 E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\winrt
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt
 .
 E:\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include
End of search list.
 "link.exe" -out:a.exe -defaultlib:libcmt -defaultlib:oldnames "-libpath:lib\\am
d64" "-libpath:atlmfc\\lib\\amd64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Ki
ts\\10\\Lib\\10.0.22621.0\\ucrt\\x64" "-libpath:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows
 Kits\\10\\Lib\\10.0.22621.0\\um\\x64" "-libpath:E:\\LLVM\\lib\\clang\\18\\lib\\
windows" -nologo "C:\\Users\\YvZhou\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\a-a20331.o"
clang: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tird to install another version of llvm,but it doesn't work.
I also tied to install Windows SDK in VS.
This is my CPATH:
E:\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include;E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include;E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include;E:\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt;
I hope it can be solved.
Thank you.

Unfortunately the comments from Staging ground are missing. As you seem to have found the solution, you can create an answer to your own question or just delete the question.

If you don't plan to delete the question, you should still replace your title with the relevant error message.
